# How can I get values from few rows to one in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need this values in first row. Can you help me?

[image]

Final work:

```
1 | 199 | 'no' | 'yes' | 'correct' |
```

Thanks for a help!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27868/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select
 max(id),
 max(C_01),
 max(C_02),
 max(C_03)
from 
 tbl
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a03890/2)